# How to unzip gz file using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, gzip

I need to extract a gz file that I have downloaded from an FTP site to a local Windows file server. I have the variables set for the local path of the file, and I know it can be used by GZIP muddle.

How can I do this? The file inside the GZ file is an XML file.

Comment: Can we see what you have tried please?

Comment: Why is this so downvoted? The question can't be that bad given that there are 2 answers with above unitary upvotes.

Comment: @PauloNeves probably because the question shows no research at all from its author.

Answer (score 280):

```
import gzip
import shutil
with gzip.open('file.txt.gz', 'rb') as f_in:
    with open('file.txt', 'wb') as f_out:
        shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
```

Comment: why did you put a second with? is that common practice? you can open several files with the same context manager

Comment: Probably because you read f_in and write f_out.  According to the docs you need params for read obj and a write obj, https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj.

Comment: @Matt Shouldnt u also close f_in and f_out ?

Comment: @JeyJ : this is the purpose of the 'with' statement. It executes f_in.close() at the exist of the "with" section. Really useful if something is going wrong (like an exception). It makes sure that the resource is closed

Comment: Note that [`shutil.copyfileobj()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj) has a third parameter `length`: *"The integer length, if given, is the buffer size. In particular, a negative length value means to copy the data without looping over the source data in chunks; by default the data is read in chunks to avoid uncontrolled memory consumption."*

Comment: How can I simply extract the file in the .gz? In your example, it is assumed that you know the filename within the gz file.  I just want to simply unzip the gz file and save all the files within gz with its original names and saved under the current folder.

Comment: @Yu Xiang, gzip can only hold one file at the time, that's why it's often use with a tar archive. If you have a .tar.gz or a .tgz file, you should take a look at the tar module, not the gzip module.

Comment: This one should be, by far, the accepted answer.

Answer (score 66):

[From the documentation:](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html#examples-of-usage)

```
import gzip
with gzip.open('file.txt.gz', 'rb') as f:
    file_content = f.read()
```

Comment: this solution works for me on python 2.7 without importing any library, @heinst thanks a lot

Comment: Just to note that this could blow up your memory as it will decompress everything into RAM at once. If you just want to decompress the file without loading it, the accepted answer by Matt is best.

Comment: @Michael This was taken straight from the Python docs at the time, so tell them that

Answer (score 27):

### Maybe you want pass it to pandas also.

```
with gzip.open('features_train.csv.gz') as f:

    features_train = pd.read_csv(f)

features_train.head()
```

Comment: What has this got to do with Pandas? "***The file inside the GZ file is an XML file***" -- OP

Comment: This is a very helpful answer. Users might land on this page from a search engine, and pandas handles xml files quite well actually.

Answer (score 11):

```
from sh import gunzip

gunzip('/tmp/file1.gz')
```

Comment: Note that `sh` is not part of the standard install.

Comment: I believe this is the straightforward solution

Answer (score 9):

Not an exact answer because you're using xml data and there is currently no `pd.read_xml()` function (as of v0.23.4), but pandas (starting with v0.21.0) can uncompress the file for you! Thanks Wes!

```
import pandas as pd
import os
fn = '../data/file_to_load.json.gz'
print(os.path.isfile(fn))
df = pd.read_json(fn, lines=True, compression='gzip')
df.tail()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: great answer. It simply reads a compressed json in a very simple (pythonic) way.

Answer (score 7):

If you are parsing the file after unzipping it, don't forget to use **decode()** method, is necessary when you open a file as binary.

```
import gzip
with gzip.open(file.gz, 'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.decode().strip())
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`gzip.decompress()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.decompress) to do it:

1. read input file using `rb` mode;
2. open output file using `w` mode and `utf8` encoding;
3. `gzip.decompress()` input bytes;
4. decode what you get to `str`.
5. write `str` to output file.

```py
def decompress(infile, tofile):
    with open(infile, 'rb') as inf, open(tofile, 'w', encoding='utf8') as tof:
        decom_str = gzip.decompress(inf.read()).decode('utf-8')
        tof.write(decom_str)
```

Answer (score 4):

**It is very simple.. Here you go !!**

```
import gzip

#path_to_file_to_be_extracted

ip = sample.gzip

#output file to be filled

op = open("output_file","w") 

with gzip.open(ip,"rb") as ip_byte:
    op.write(ip_byte.read().decode("utf-8")
    wf.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the gzip (and gunzip) programs installed on your computer a simple way is to call that command from python:

```
import os
filename = 'file.txt.gz'
os.system('gunzip ' + filename)
```

optionally, if you want to preserve the original file, use

```
os.system('gunzip --keep ' + filename)
```

Comment: On older systems you might have to use gunzip -c file.txt.gz > file.txt so the command would be:
  os.system('gunzip -c ' + filename + '  > ' + filename[:-3]

Comment: os.system("gunzip path/to/filename") giving error | sh: gunzip: command not found
  but from commandline i can  use gunzip any clue why this is happening

Comment: It's possible your python distribution uses a different shell (or path settings) than your command line. Find the full path to the gunzip application ("which gunzip" on -nix systems) then enter it like

os.system('/opt/local/bin/gunzip ' + filename)

Answer (score -5):

if you have a linux environment it is very easy to unzip using the command `gunzip`.
go to the file folder and give as below

```
gunzip file-name
```