# How to extract a gz file in python

Tags: python, gzip

I have a `.gz` file, inside which there is another file. I need to extract the file inside the zipped file.

```
f = gzip.open(dest, 'rb')
```

This only opens the file but I need to download that particular file which is inside `gz` instead of just opening the `gz` file.

This question has been marked as duplicate which I accept, but I haven't found a solution where we can actually download the file and not just read its content. Same is the case with the link mentioned.

Comment: Do you want this to be saved somewhere (i.e. you want basically to implement `gunzip` in Python)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unzip gz file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31028815/how-to-unzip-gz-file-using-python)

Comment: @norok2 yes extract the file to any destination place

Comment: @Meyi I have already checked that link. There is no answer where we can download the file in actual. Please let me know which answer you are referring to.? Thanks

Comment: @SAndrew The link that Meyi posted shows how to unzip a .gz file. Do you actually want to do something else ? You mention download - do you mean you want to download the file from some web server ?

Comment: Check this link which provides an answer.<br>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31028815/how-to-unzip-gz-file-using-python

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could just open two files, read from the `gzipped` file and write to the other file (in blocks to avoid clogging the memory).

```
import gzip

def gunzip(source_filepath, dest_filepath, block_size=65536):
    with gzip.open(source_filepath, 'rb') as s_file, \
            open(dest_filepath, 'wb') as d_file:
        while True:
            block = s_file.read(block_size)
            if not block:
                break
            else:
                d_file.write(block)
```

Otherwise, you could use `shutil`, as suggested in [How to unzip gz file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31028815/how-to-unzip-gz-file-using-python):

```
import gzip
import shutil

def gunzip_shutil(source_filepath, dest_filepath, block_size=65536):
    with gzip.open(source_filepath, 'rb') as s_file, \
            open(dest_filepath, 'wb') as d_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(s_file, d_file, block_size)
```

Both solutions would work in Python 2 and 3.

Performance-wise, they are substantially equivalent, at least on my system:

```
%timeit gunzip(source_filepath, dest_filepath)
# 129 ms ± 1.89 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit gunzip_shutil(source_filepath, dest_filepath)
# 132 ms ± 2.99 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Whats its performance compare to native `gzip` command in shell?

Comment: @alper probably worse, as gzip Is doing the same but essentially in C.

Comment: Wow! It's Well For Big File Also tested on 7GB

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issue like this:

```
f = gzip.open(dest, 'r')
file_content = f.read()
file_content = file_content.decode('utf-8')
f_out = open('file', 'w+')
f_out.write(file_content)
f.close()
f_out.close()
```

dest is the file with `gz`

Comment: Your solution is sub-optimal as you may run into memory issues for large files. Besides, this is going to be slower than it could be, as you are performing unnecessary decoding.