# How to redirect gzip output to Popen stdin

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, gzip

How can I pass the result of decompressing by `gzip` into process stdin if I haven't file?

I found, that `Popen` constructor requires `stdin` argument to be the object with the `fileno` method. In python2.7 `gzip` hasn't `decompress` function. Also, why `Popen` can't accept file object without `fileno`?

I have tried this code

```py
import subprocess
import gzip
import io

# To test with file
# with open('test.gz', 'rb') as f:
#    data = f.read()
data = b'...'

gz = gzip.GzipFile(mode='rb', fileobj=io.BytesIO(data))
subprocess.Popen(['cat'], stdin=gz)
```

But have the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    subprocess.Popen(['cat'], stdin=gz)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 728, in __init__
    errread, errwrite) = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1347, in _get_handles
    p2cread = stdin.fileno()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/gzip.py", line 334, in fileno
    return self.fileobj.fileno()
io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno
```

**Added:**
It's ok to use something different from `Popen` and/or `subprocess`

Answer (score 0):

you can save it in a file and pass the file path to Popen constructor, i'm not sure if it works with BytesIO module.

You can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31028815/how-to-unzip-gz-file-using-python) question on how to save the output to a file.

GLHF

Comment: I thought about using a temporary file. But it's a bit hacky

Comment: The error ```io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno``` reffers to the Type of variable that you are trying to use the ```fileno()``` function, it only works with fileObjects, he expecting something likely, not a io.BytesIO, as you are passing.
I think you need to create the file in order to use the module. At least open it with ```with```, read the bytes into  a file and pass the file variable to Popen.

Comment: Yes, I understand why does error exist. But the question is why `Popen` allows only file objects with `fileno` and is it possible somehow pass data to process without a file. Maybe without `Popen` or even without `subprocess`