# how can we unzip a gunzip file that contains csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, gzip

I'm trying to unzip a gunzip file in to .csv file , I tried different methods, still it is not getting the result i want, if any one make me understand how it is being unzipped in back end, that would be a great help.

I also tried this code:

```
csv_file = open("xyz.csv", 'wb')
writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=df.columns.to_list())
writer.writeheader()
writer.writerows(df.to_dict())
csv_file.close()

this above code is throwing bad zip file error
```

Comment: Are you looking to read from the zip file or write to it?

Comment: @JonSG first  i'm reading so that i will create dataframe, with that i can create a csv file. main aim is here to unzip the csv file from it. In second approach i tried to create it using csv module.

Comment: Ah, so your main objective is to unzip an existing zip file. If you have an existing OS utility, one easy way would be to use `subprocess.call()`. If you want to do this all in python, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31028815/how-to-unzip-gz-file-using-python

Comment: Please provide the first 30 bytes of the file in hexadecimal, so we can see what it really is.

Comment: guys thanks for your support, it worked with this code: went ahead read
properly pandas documentation,
    df = pd.read_csv('xyz.cxv.gz', compression='gzip', header=0, sep='|',
                                 quotechar='"')                            
                                 
                                 
    df.to_csv("xyz.csv",mode='w', header=True,index=False, sep='|',
                                             quotechar='"')