# Convert eurostat table of contents PDF to JSON

Tags: python, json, database, pdf

Since there is no accessable API to the EUROSTAT data, each query should be created manually I found [this table of contents](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/estat-navtree-portlet-prod/BulkDownloadListing?sort=1&file=table_of_contents_en.pdf) And I want to extract it to a searchable JSON. In the file there are section titles, and each leaf has 3 links, But how can I connect links and titles and sections into a JSON?

I have this basic code:

```py
PDFFile = open("table_of_contents_en.pdf",'rb')

PDF = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(PDFFile)
pages = PDF.getNumPages()
key = '/Annots'
uri = '/URI'
ank = '/A'

for page in range(1,2):
    print("Current Page: {}".format(page))
    pageSliced = PDF.getPage(page)
    pageObject = pageSliced.getObject()
    if key in pageObject.keys():
        ann = pageObject[key]
        for a in ann:
            u = a.getObject()
            if uri in u[ank].keys():
                print(u[ank][uri])
```

And this for text:

```
pdfFileObj = open('table_of_contents_en.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
print(pdfReader.numPages)
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)
print(pageObj.extractText())
pdfFileObj.close()
```

and this for  download zips:

```py
for page in range(1,2):
    print("Current Page: {}".format(page))
    pageSliced = PDF.getPage(page)
    pageObject = pageSliced.getObject()
    if key in pageObject.keys():
        ann = pageObject[key]
        for a in ann:
            u = a.getObject()
            if uri in u[ank].keys():
                print(u[ank][uri])
            if str(u[ank].keys()).find(".tsv.gz") != -1 :
                url = str(u[ank].keys())
                r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
                print(str(str(str(u[ank].keys()).split("/")[-1]).split(".")[0])
                open(str(str(str(u[ank].keys()).split("/")[-1]).split(".")[0]), 'wb').write(r.content)
```

But how can I do this at the same time correctly, in some structured data?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, this won't be a JSON, but the list of files in a folder can be converted to, here is how to get the files:

```
import PyPDF2
import requests

PDFFile = open("table_of_contents_en.pdf",'rb')

PDF = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(PDFFile)
pages = PDF.getNumPages()
key = '/Annots'
uri = '/URI'
ank = '/A'

for page in range(pages):
    print("Current Page: {}".format(page))
    pageSliced = PDF.getPage(page)
    pageObject = pageSliced.getObject()
    if key in pageObject.keys():
        ann = pageObject[key]
        for a in ann:
            u = a.getObject()
            # if uri in u[ank].keys():
            #   print(u[ank][uri])
            if str(u[ank][uri]).find(".tsv.gz") != -1 :
                url = str(u[ank][uri])
                try:
                    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
                    print(str(str(str(url).split("/")[-1]).split(".")[0]))
                    open(str(str(url).split("/")[-1]), 'wb').write(r.content)
                except:
                    print("ERROR ON" + url)
```

### Usage:

1. Download the table of contents file from Eurostat: http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/estat-navtree-portlet-prod/BulkDownloadListing?sort=1&file=table_of_contents_en.pdf
2. run `python3`  the code above, edited with the file name, if it has changed.
3. extract with some tool the downloaded `.gz` files *(suggestion: [How to unzip gz file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31028815/how-to-unzip-gz-file-using-python) )*
4. delete the `.gz` files.

Full code on: [https://github.com](https://github.com/gabboraron/felhoszamitasi_rendszerek/tree/main/datasets/eurostat_data)