# Extract data from .gz file

Tags: python, gzip

I'm trying to open a .gz file (it is just .gz, not .log.gz or anything else), but reading the file line by line is only displaying gibberish. It should be having sensor data.

This is my code:

```
import gzip

with gzip.open('data.gz','r') as fin:        
    for line in fin:        
        print('got line', line)
```

Here is an example of the output:

```
b'\x80\x04\x95\x90\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x1bsklearn.preprocessing._data\x94\x8c\x0eStandardScaler\x94\x93\x94)\x81\x94}\x94(\x8c\twith_mean\x94\x88\x8c\x08with_std\x94\x88\x8c\x04copy\x94\x88\x8c\x0en_features_in_\x94K\x08\x8c\x0fn_samples_seen_\x94\x8c\x15numpy.core.multiarray\x94\x8c\x06scalar\x94\x93\x94\x8c\x05numpy\x94\x8c\x05dtype\x94\x93\x94\x8c\x02i8\x94K\x00K\x01\x87\x94R\x94(K\x03\x8c\x01<\x94NNNJ\xff\xff\xff\xffJ\xff\xff\xff\xffK\x00t\x94bC\x08\xae\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x94\x86\x94R\x94\x8c\x05mean_\x94\x8c\x13joblib.numpy_pickle\x94\x8c\x11NumpyArrayWrapper\x94\x93\x94)\x81\x94}\x94(\x8c\x08subclass\x94h\r\x8c\x07ndarray\x94\x93\x94\x8c\x05shape\x94K\x08\x85\x94\x8c\x05order\x94\x8c\x01C\x94\x8c\x05dtype\x94h\x0f\x8c\x02f8\x94K\x00K\x01\x87\x94R\x94(K\x03h\x13NNNJ\xff\xff\xff\xffJ\xff\xff\xff\xffK\x00t\x94b\x8c\n'
b'allow_mmap\x94\x88ub*\xd4\xff\xe6\xbd\rE@\x15\xd1=A5\xdfg@\x0f\x7fv\x94\xabjg@\x04?\xf0\x03?0^@v\x94\xab\xda\xb5\xb6E@\x9bz\xec\xdd\x90\x9e?@\x13\xd7\xa8J\x94\x92;@*\x1f\xc6\xfd\xba$7@\x95&\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x04var_\x94h\x1b)\x81\x94}\x94(h\x1eh h!K\x08\x85\x94h#h$h%h(h*\x88ub\x8f\x16F\x8b\xed\n'
b'T@\x01^\xd6u\xfd\x94\xa9@Z\xae\xc2d\xb0\x05\x9a@\xe7\xbb\xeeu.$\x85@~\xd7\xe2\xe7_@F@\xb0$HdS\x17F@*\xa8\x07o\x16]}@\x1e\xba\xc0\xc8r]<@\x95(\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x06scale_\x94h\x1b)\x81\x94}\x94(h\x1eh h!K\x08\x85\x94h#h$h%h(h*\x88ub\x8fDh\n'
b'Z\xe8!@E\xaa1\xf0\x91\x9cL@Q\xecq~\xa0gD@\x13m$\x9e\x92\x02:@\xe9>L\x19(\xaf\x1a@DZ\xf9\xbd\x7f\x96\x1a@~\x014y\xdf\xac5@y\xa3\xc0X\xb4M\x15@\x95\x1f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x10_sklearn_version\x94\x8c\x060.24.1\x94ub.'
```

Comment: `gz` is a type of zipped file (gzip). You will have to [gunzip it to read it](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html).

Comment: [`gzip.open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.open)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python: read lines from compressed text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566558/python-read-lines-from-compressed-text-files)

Comment: How are you "trying to open" ? Can you post a [example] of your script / code ?

Comment: We'd need to inspect the data to reproduce this. The most obvious-on-its-face explanation is that the data file doesn't really include gzipped text. Can you build a [mre] that works with known-good data (say, that includes instructions for how to create your data file with an obviously-correct process like `printf '%s\n' "first line" "second line" | gzip >data.gz`)?

Comment: See https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/OblongScaredClient#main.sh -- the code works fine when we create a known-good input file

Comment: You forgot to call the decode function. Here an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58693033/17766295)

Comment: @Nabil, if the OP was just saying they got `b'something'` instead of `something`, that's hardly "gibberish" as the question describes. I doubt very much that it's just a problem of failing to convert between Unicode and bytes (or, rather, if it is this is a very poorly-asked question).

Comment: @AlwaysWonder, ...keep in mind that anything can be gzipped -- that includes binary data, so unless you have reason to know that your sensor data is text instead of packed binary data, there's no particular reason to _expect_ it to be human-readable after the compression is undone.

Comment: Much as a foreign language you do not know would appear to be gibberish.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [unpickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) the result of the decompression to reconstruct the saved data.